# Rails 5 Active Storage: Is there a more efficient way of displaying multiple image attachments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activestorage

I have a model named `Job`. It has one Active Storage attachment.

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  has_one_attached :image
end
```

I will eventually paginate the results but at the moment, `JobsController#index` returns all jobs:

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @jobs = Job.all
  end
end
```

Since all 2000 seeded rows are displayed on the index page, I can see that loaded all images takes a long time.

```
<% @jobs.each do |job| %>
<div class="listing">
  <div class="image">
    <%= image_tag url_for(job.image) %>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

Eventually, I only intend to display 50 or so at a time but this has led me to wondering if there isn't a more efficient way of loading multiple images.

What steps do I need to take to ensure that images are delivered quickly and with minimal strain on the app? Am I doing it in the most efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails has a method for retrieving associations all at once. It's called "eager loading" and in your case it would look like this:

```
@jobs = Job.with_attached_image.all
```

This grabs all `@jobs` with images attached already. This is a special case because it's using the Rails `has_one_attached` model attribute. Normally, we handle preloading nested associations like:

```
@jobs.includes(:image)
```

Source: [Rails Eager Loading](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations)

Eager loading will make your queries a lot simpler and faster.